# Properties - from C# to Objective C

Tags: c#, objective-c, properties

Does anyone know the objective c equivalent of the get set functionality in c#?

Here is an example of what I want to convert from:

```
 public double pBal 
        { 
            get
             { 
                return balance; //pBal;
             } 
            set 
            { 
                balance = value;
             } 
        }
```

Comment: Note: the getter will cause stack overflow/infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, getters and setters are collectively called "accessors". You don't need to define accessors for simple properties. Defining a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) will cause the compiler to generate accessors. For more complex properties, getters are nullary methods with typically the same name as the property, and setters are unary methods with "set" prepended to the name.

Your example would be implemented manually as:

```
-(double)pBal {
    return balance;
}
-(void)setPBal:(double)newBalance {
    balance = newBalance;
}
```

This is equivalent to what's generated by:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) double pBal;
...
@synthesize pBal=balance;
```

## Custom Accessors

More complex accessors generated by the compiler will take into account retaining and synchronization. I believe:

```
@property (retain) NSString* name;
...
@synthesize name;
```

will generate accessors similar to:

```
-(NSString*)name {
    @synchronized(name) {
        return [[name retain] autorelease];
    }
}
-(void)name:(NSString*)aString {
    @synchronized(name) {
        if (name != aString) {
            [name release];
            name = [aString retain];
        }
    }
}
```

The actual accessors may use locks rather than `@synchronized` blocks, which can have an affect with recursive properties and exceptions.

## Naming Accessors

The default naming rules for [accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE) come from [key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i). Boolean-valued getters usually use "is" as a prefix. Note there's nothing special about booleans in this regard–neither the language nor the compiler forces "is..." methods to return a `BOOL`–it's simply a matter of convention.

```
-(BOOL)isReady {
    return ready;
}
-(void)setReady:(BOOL)aBool {
    ready = aBool;
}
```

You can override the [default accessor names](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW25) using the "getter" and "setter" attributes in the property declaration.

```
@property (getter=dateAsString) NSString *displayDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Properties

Example Header

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
    @public
        NSString *name;
    @private
        int age;
}

@property(copy) NSString *name;
@property(readonly) int age;

-(id)initWithAge:(int)age;
@end
```

---

Example Class

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;

-(id)initWithAge:(int)initAge {
    age = initAge; // NOTE: direct instance variable assignment, not property setter
    return self;
}

-(int)age {
    return age; // wiki had 29 here, not sure why. Edited to return age. 
}
@end
```

---

It may still be wise to study how Objective-C does memory management, even with Automatic Reference Counting on the horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly like that you need to create the method for getting and setting. C# provides that method as a shortcut.

The Interface

```
@interface SimpleCar : NSObject {
    NSString* make;
    NSString* model;
    NSNumber* vin;
}

// set methods
- (void) setVin:   (NSNumber*)newVin;
- (void) setMake:  (NSString*)newMake;
- (void) setModel: (NSString*)setModel;

// convenience method
- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake
        andModel: (NSString*)newModel;

@end
```

And the Implementation

```
@implementation SimpleCar

// set methods
- (void) setVin: (NSNumber*)newVin {
    [vin release];
    vin = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    vin = newVin;
}

- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake {
    [make release];
    make = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newMake];
}

- (void) setModel: (NSString*)newModel {
    [model release];
    model = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newModel];
}

// convenience method
- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake
        andModel: (NSString*)newModel {
    // Reuse our methods from earlier
    [self setMake:newMake];
    [self setModel:newModel];
}

// get methods
- (NSString*) make {
    return make;
}

- (NSString*) model {
    return model;
}

- (NSNumber*) vin {
    return vin;
}

@end
```